# flutter_moor filter select query using more than one value inside where

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, filter, flutter-moor

I am trying to implement a multiple values filter to my database using flutter's `moor` package.

`moor` already has `where` method that takes an expression and converts it into sql statement. like:

```
 (select(exercisesTable)..where((e) => (e.name.equals(name)))).get();
```

But I need to filter data due to more one value.
After I searched in the documentation I have found two possible solutions:

1. Use `CutomExpressionClass` [link](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/expressions/#custom-expressions):

   ```
   Expression expression = CustomExpression<bool, BoolType>(" water BETWEEN 4.0 AND 5.0 AND protein BETWEEN 4.0 AND 15.0 AND description LIKE CHESS%");
   ```

   But I get this error : *

   > SqliteException: near ";": syntax error, SQL logic error

*

2. Use `Custom select statements` [link](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/using-sql/custom_queries/#custom-select-statements):
   I have not tried this because, I believe the problem is in sql itself not moor package.

Comment: https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/expressions/#boolean-algebra

Comment: So, I should learn how to read carefully. It is definitly what I need, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments of the **SingleTableQueryMixin::where** method ([link](https://github.com/simolus3/moor/blob/5cbc331ddaf7a3031d98a905c2e05080d9fbb2c8/moor/lib/src/runtime/query_builder/statements/query.dart#L170)):

```
...      
/// If a where condition has already been set before, the resulting filter
/// will be the conjunction of both calls.
...
```

According to this you can use something like that:

```
 Future<List<TableData>> getTableList({int position, int type}) {
     final _select = select(table);
     if (position != null) {
        _select..where((tbl) => tbl.position.equals(position));
     }
     if (type != null) {
        _select..where((tbl) => tbl.type.equals(type));
     }
     return _select.get();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [boolean algebra](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/expressions/#boolean-algebra) feature to have multiple where conditions.

```
// find all animals that aren't mammals and have 4 legs
select(animals)..where((a) => a.isMammal.not() & a.amountOfLegs.equals(4));

// find all animals that are mammals or have 2 legs
select(animals)..where((a) => a.isMammal | a.amountOfLegs.equals(2));
```